# Make crispy rice noodles without frying

Tags: baking, frying, rice

Everywhere I've read about cooking puffed rice noodles says that the soaked noodles need to be fried. I need a less messy alternative to frying. Is there a way I could bake them to get the same or similar consistency?

Comment: Why is frying too messy? Grease spatters?

Comment: grease spatters, cleaning the oil off the pan... I mean it's not a big deal, I'm just wondering if anyone has had success with an alternative method

Comment: To stop spatters, you can use a splatter screen (http://www.google.com/products?hl=en&q=splatter+screen). It is a fine mesh that stops oil splatter while letting moisture escape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no... deep frying is necessary because you need the water inside the noodles to flash to steam, which creates the puff. baking is a slow and indirect heat and therefore will not work.